# sending email using PutEmail processor in Nifi - Failing with Error

Tags: smtp, gmail, apache-nifi

I am trying to send email using PutEmail processor in Nifi. Below is the configuration of the processor.

[image: configuration of PutEmail]

However, emails are not sent and getting this error. It would be great help if addressed.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Did you visit the link recommended by the error message? Did it help? Are you certain the SMTP configu and credentials are correct? Is SMTP relay enabled on that GMail acct? etc.

Comment: 1. implement https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol 2, make sure the user doesnt have 2fa enabled.

Answer (score 2):

@techno_mad -   I would trust the error message.   Test with a known working smtp combo with 100% confirmed smtp access.    I also suggest, paste the nifi error as text, not an image.  Your peers need to visit the link and are likely not typing it out.

https://support.google.com/mail/thread/5621336?hl=en

> Test enabling “Access for less secure apps” (which just means the
> client/app doesn’t use OAuth 2.0 - https://oauth.net/2/) for the
> account you are trying to access.  It's found in the account settings
> on the Security tab, Account permissions (not available to accounts
> with 2-step verification enabled):
> https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Suggestion taken! Will paste in the text format. “Access for less secure apps” is enabled in email ID. Will check out the links shared and update. Thank you!

Comment: Resolved!!! Issue was with  set up... Thanks @steven-dfheinz